# Insert into External Object

Tags: insert, externalobjects, heroku-connect

We have set up a postgres on Heroku. Using Heroku Connect we have exposed couple of tables as external object following this [link][1] . We are able to read the data in Salesforce. But when we are trying to insert, we are getting this error:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

We have set up the data as "Writable data", not sure what else has to be set up for making external object writable. Any pointers are appreciated!
[1]: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-external-objects-salesforce
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I04jv.png